# How can I use photoshop to open a file in filter plugin at Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, photoshop

I used  the function system("open file"), it works well in any other program.
For example, system("open /tmp/1.psd"), this code can use photoshop open the file 1.psd .
But it just don't work in my photoshop plugin program.
How can I use photoshop filter plugin to open a file in Mac OS X?
Now I just want to try other way to open a file in Mac OS X.
In windows, the shellExecute works well.
I have read the following links
[OSX equivalent of ShellExecute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859517/osx-equivalent-of-shellexecute).
It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for OS X.